# Why am I getting this "Couldn't load requested aspect" error?

Tags: errors, listings

I want to include some Matlab scripts in my thesis. Unfortunately, I can't get `listings` to work properly. If I try to compile the following code,

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
Bla bla bla.
\end{document}
```

I get the following error:

```
Package Listings Error: Couldn't load requested
aspect\lst@RequireAspects\lst@loadaspects
```

Why is that happening and what can I do to remedy the problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your example compiles without any problem. Please add a small example of your listings code too, perhaps you made an error/typo so far?

Comment: If you get that exact error from this particular MWE, please also post the log file.

Comment: I can reproduce the error by emulating a bad installation, where only `listings.sty` is present, but not all its accompanying files. How did you install `listings`?

Comment: The complete distribution of `listings` requires the files `listings.cfg`, `lstdoc.sty`, `lstlang2.sty`, `lstmisc.sty` `listings.sty`, `lstlang1.sty` and `lstlang3.sty`

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

The error is caused by `listings` not finding some required subpackages.

The complete distribution has the following files:

```
listings.cfg
lstdoc.sty
listings.sty
lstlang1.sty
lstlang2.sty
lstlang3.sty
lstmisc.sty
```

Of these, `lstdoc.sty` is only needed for typesetting the package documentation. 
My conjecture is that you only downloaded `listings.sty`, but not the other ones.

You can download them at http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings and extract the files with the `Makefile`. However, since `listings` is included in all standard distributions, you shouldn't install it manually, but with the facilities provided by your TeX distribution.

***Note:*** something more can be said if you specify what TeX distribution you're using.

Comment: I have the same problem, and when I look at my installation, which is texlive from homebrew, all of the above files are installed:
```
$ ls /opt/homebrew/Cellar/texlive/20220321/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/
listings-acm.prf      listings-lua.prf     lstdoc.sty    lstmisc.sty
listings-bash.prf     listings-python.prf  lstlang1.sty
listings-fortran.prf  listings.cfg         lstlang2.sty
listings-hansl.prf    listings.sty         lstlang3.sty
```
the error comes when pdflatex is trying to load `listmisc.sty` from this directory.

Comment: @RobertP.Goldman On macOS, install [MacTeX](https://tug.org/mactex/)

Comment: Actually, it turned out that I had auto-generated latex from org-mode, and that gave me a defective form that looked like this: `\usepackage[""]{listings}`. I took out the optional argument altogether and everything was fine. Kind of a terrible error message, though.